# mysqld_multi: separate [mysqldN] groups into own my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'd like to separate each **[mysqldN]**-group into his own **my.cnf**.

I tried an extra **.my.cnf** or **my.cnf** into the homedir of the user, which runs the mysqld-process. Doesn't work.

/etc/my.cnf:

```
...
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld                          = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin                      = /usr/bin/mysqladmin

[mysqld1]
basedir                         = /usr
bind-address                    = 127.0.0.1
character-set-server            = utf8mb4
...
```

/home/user1/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld2]
basedir                         = /usr
bind-address                    = 127.0.0.1
character-set-server            = utf8mb4
...
```

**mysqld_multi report** should report each server, which contains in /etc/my.cnf and e.g. /home/user1/my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using [mysqld_multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-multi.html):

> mysqld_multi is designed to manage several mysqld processes that
>   listen for connections on different Unix socket files and TCP/IP
>   ports. It can start or stop servers, or report their current status.
>
> mysqld_multi searches for groups named [mysqldN] in my.cnf (or in the
>   file named by the --defaults-file option). N can be any positive
>   integer. This number is referred to in the following discussion as the
>   option group number, or GNR. Group numbers distinguish option groups
>   from one another and are used as arguments to mysqld_multi to specify
>   which servers you want to start, stop, or obtain a status report for.
>   Options listed in these groups are the same that you would use in the
>   [mysqld] group used for starting mysqld.

Apart from mysql's official documentation, Percona also has a good blog post [on this topic](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/08/26/mysqld_multi-how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-mysql/), which has sample config files.

Comment: Well, i read that, but this contains the same thing that i already tried. A global my.cnf which contains every group.

Comment: Reading is not the same as implementing, or at least understanding. It also points out that you need to run a different daemon, not simply mysql. Since you have not indicated what exactly you had done, I cannot help you any further.

Comment: 1. You should have a single my.cnf, not multiple ones. 2. Datadirs shoukd not be the same. 3. Have you read the percona blog post I linked in the answer? It has lots of examples.

Comment: I already did and it doesn't contain the answer, for what i asked here. There are not the same data-dir's as well as the mysqld_multi is already running. I simply asked for, if it's possbile to split this global my.cnf into separates. Doesn't look like.

Comment: Then do not use mysql_multi, just install separate mysql binaries as separate daemons.

Answer (score 0):

If want separate .cnf file for each `[mysqldN]`-group you can include in `/etc/my.cnf` the `!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d` line, so now, for each `[mysqldN]` group you can have a separate file `mysqldN.cnf` in `/etc/my.cnf.d`dir. This is copied form MariaDB standard configuration file on SLES 12 SP2.